# How to find k in contrasts, where comparing one group against multiple groups in a sample

Tags: statistics, contrast

I am having trouble understanding how to conduct contrasts where comparing the mean of one group to the average mean of multiple groups.
My understanding so far, is that the Contrast (C) =  mu1- (mu2+mu3...mug)/g
And that C must be divided by the standard error to obtain the t-value.
I am having trouble obtaining the standard error, for example, where you are comparing one group in the sample to that of 3 other groups, where you treat the 3 other groups as a single group, so C = mu1 - (mu2+mu3+mu4)/3.
I know that pooled standard deviation * SQRT(sum(k^2/n)) is an approach, but I don't know how to decide on k.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.